# Pass date object through javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this object `@item.DataInicio` which is a date and I want it to pass through a javascript function

```
function checkweek(data) {     
   alert(data);
}
```

I call the function using a button:

```
input type"button" onclick="checkweek(@item.DataInicio)"
```

But it doesn't give the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing date parameter to js function, pass it within quoatation '' as shown below

```
<input type"button" onclick="checkweek('@item.DataInicio')" />
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm new here

Comment: Can you tell me how do I get the week number from that date? I can't use the date for anything else inside the function.

Comment: There is no built in c# method to get the 'day of the week'. you might need  to do some manual calculation and then pass it to the js function as another parameter.